# How to set source (git link) for cocoapod dependency

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods

I forked Amazon SDK to alter some behavior and use it via cocoapods.
In podfile it looks like

```
pod 'AWSiOSSDKv2', :git => "https://github.com/vGubriienko/aws-sdk-ios.git", :tag => '2.2.2.BT', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

Unfortunately in latest releases they moved from idea of one pod to root pod + subspec for each of their service.
And when I installed updated version first time I discovered that updated pod uses actually not updated subpods (like version 2.2.2 instead of version 2.2.2.BT).

Investigation showed that I also need to update all altered podspecs. And there is a problem. AWSS3 podspec have a dependency:

```
s.dependency 'AWSCore'
```

But this dependency looks at the original pod instead of my altered fork. I tried to use something like:

```
s.dependency 'AWSCore', :git => 'https://github.com/vGubriienko/aws-sdk-ios.git', :tag => '2.2.2.BT'
```

But cocoapods failed to install the pod in this case.